# How to extract bitarray from its byte representation of the bitarray in original format

Tags: python, bitarray

For the following code `a` and `c` are not comparable. Even though they are same logically.

Here, `a` is not equal to `c` since they have different length? How to overcome this problem in an efficient way?

```
from bitarray import bitarray

a = bitarray('1', endian="little") * 5
b = a.tobytes()
c = bitarray(endian='little')
c.frombytes(b)

print(a == c)
```

Comment: Dear SO, please stop people asking about the "most efficient" way. Thank you.

Comment: Overcome it how?  They are different.  You will likely need to specify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: How could they be equal if they're different lengths?

Comment: print them out and you will see. You  are making assumptions about the bitarray package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the bitarray 0.8 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/

- tobytes does not preserve length in bits
- and thus frombytes always create a bitarray of length=n*8

Workarounds

- the most painless workaround would be extending the size of both arrays to a multiple of 8. There is no such operation
- the second most painless workaround is running a tobytes-frombytes pair on both arrays before comparison. This way their length will become a multiple of 8
- alternatively unpack and pack probably preserve the exact length, just they use 1 byte for representing 1 bit

As far as I checked the current implementation always assume that the content of two bitarrays are different if their length differs. Even bitdiff starts with such check, while one could assume that the shorter array gets virtually extended with 0-s for such comparison.

EDIT:
In-place extension may be possible. I can not tell if it is nice Python code or not, but something like this may work:

```
a.extend(max(0, c.length()-a.length()) * bitarray([False]))
c.extend(max(0, a.length()-c.length()) * bitarray([False]))
```

In my imagination by running these lines the shorter bitarray gets extended with 0-s and have an equal length to the other bitarray. In practice I have no idea how the `0*bitarray([False])` behaves and can not test it now.
If it misbehaves, a traditional

```
if c.length()<a.length(): c.extend(a.length()-c.length()) * bitarray([False])
elif a.length()<c.length(): a.extend(c.length()-a.length()) * bitarray([False])
```

can ensure that `0*bitarray([False])` never occurs.